# set governor on intel_pstate cpu

Tags: kernel, cpu, intel

I'm trying to `sudo echo 100 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct`

or to change the governor through `sudo cpupower -c 1 frequency-set -g performance`

but none works, the second one tells me ok but when I check frequency-info I get the lowest possible frequency and the governors are still `performance, powersave`:

`analyzing CPU 1:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 1
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 1
  maximum transition latency: 0.97 ms.
  hardware limits: 1.20 GHz - 2.60 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 2.60 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.20 GHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  boost state support:
    Supported: no
    Active: no
    2600 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
    2600 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
    2600 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
    2600 MHz max turbo 1 active cores`